Every closed ideal of a Banach *-algebra with approximate identity is semiprime?
An ideal $I$ of an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ is called semiprime if  $J^2 \subseteq I$ implies $J\subset I$ for all ideals $J$. It is known that every closed ideal of a $C^{\ast}$-algebra is semiprime.

Is it true that every closed ideal of a Banach *-algebra with approximate identity is semiprime?


No. Take $\mathcal A=\mathbb C[x]/(x^2)=\mathbb C\oplus \mathbb C[x]$, where

$\|a+bx\|=|a|+|b|$
$(a+bx)^*=\overline{a} +\overline{b}x$

It has an identity, and any ideal is closed since it has finite dimension.
Let $J=\langle x \rangle$, then $J^2=\{0\}$, but $J\not\subset \{0\}$.
This is a useful example to illustrate many differences between Banach $*$- and $C^*$- algebras, such as this one and this one.

This is an excellent example. My Banach/C* algebras theory course was focused more on "analytic" spaces, so it is nice to see a more "algebraic" example.

Banach $$-algebras are invented to study spaces of functions with analysis background, more or less, but the axioms are quite weak that allow pathological examples like this.  On the contrary, $C^$-algebras and Von Neumann algebras are extremelty robust (so they allow better classification theory).
